# VLC Media Player - Dolby TrueHD only outputs 2 channels

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, vlc-media-player, surround-sound

I've been working on this for 2 days now with no success. I am on Windows 10 and audio is going from my pc to Yamaha Aventage RX-A2030 via HDMI. I have a gigabyte GA-Z77Z-UD5H motherboard. I am using the file found here for testing: [Demolandia.net](https://www.demolandia.net/downloads.html?id=48882118)
My windows audio setup is correct because it works beautifully with the awful Windows Media Player but not with VLC. I have tried everything I can in both simple and advanced settings but still only 2 channels. I've tried every output module, I've tried forcing Dolby detection, I've tried disabling audio resampler, I've enabled HDMI passthrough (this got DTS and Dolby Digital + working). Nothing works for Dolby TrueHD. Does VLC not support this surround mode when WMP does?  Can anyone else get 7.1 output from that Demolandia file on VLC?

Comment: Did you try switching VLC's audio output to 'Built-in Digital Output (Encoded Output)' That's the usual trick for Mac, idk about Win. Basically, VLC cannot itself process 'patented' audio codecs, for licensing reasons; it can only pass them to an external decoder.

Comment: That's not an option.  I've tried switching to every available output "Module" with no success.  Output "Device" must be on my TV (which is my receiver) to have any sound at all.  I then have HDMI Passthrough enabled.  With passthrough enabled it will pass DTS and Dolby Digital just fine but not Dolby TrueHD. Trust me, I wouldn't want VLC to process codecs even if it could.  That is what my very expensive receiver is for.